# Can Fortran pointer assignment be overloaded through a type-bound generic procedure?

Tags: pointers, fortran, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload the pointer assignment in Fortran? i.e. given a type

```
Module test
type :: pointerType
    real, pointer :: value
contains
    generic :: assignment(=>) => ptToValue !This is not legitimate syntax, (I've tried it using ifort) but does suggest the intent of question
    ...
end type

contains

subroutine ptToValue(self,other)
    type(pointerType), intent(inout) :: self
    real, target, intent(in) :: other
    self%value=>other
    end subroutine
end module
```

you could create an array of that type and associate elements like this

```
...
type(pointerType), dimension(50) :: example
real, target :: realvalue
...
example(3)=>realvalue
```

rather than like this

```
...
example(3)%value=>realvalue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Instead, simply invoke the subroutine directly or through a binding.  If  your compiler supports the relevant parts of F2008, consider making the other argument a pointer.

Comment: How disappointing. IanH - you've been very helpful, I appreciate that greatly.