# Overload arrow operator (=>) in fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran, operator-overloading, overloading

I just started overloading operators (including assignment) in Fortran 2003, and I want to overload the arrow operator (=>) for my user-defined type.
I know for most operators, like (+), I would say

```
interface operator(+)  
    ! What I want this to mean instead  
end interface operator
```

But, that doesn't work for (=>). I know for assignment, I would say

```
interface assignment(=)  
    ! What I want this to mean instead  
end interface assignment
```

which still doesn't work for (=>).

Specifically, I define a type where the underlying data is a pointer.

```
type my_type
    integer, pointer :: data(:)
end type my_type
```

So, when I say

```
type (my_type) :: a
integer, target :: b(4)

! Do stuff to b
a => b
```

I'd like this to mean

```
a%data => b
```

Thank you for any suggestions! Answers in standards other than the 2003 standard will also be helpful.

Comment: Thankfully, it seems you cannot do what you want.  In your example above, what if the declaration is `type(my_type), pointer :: a`.  What does `a => b` mean?  Is this a syntax error?

Comment: Please note that `=>` [isn't an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31885866/3157076).  The question here covers `=` not being an operator, so it's worth stressing that pointer assignment isn't one either.

Comment: @Steve I was hoping to reference you in my comment to the answer. See below if you're interested. I'm used to having to explicitly dereference pointers in C++, so your comment definitely helped me understand Fortran better.

Comment: @francescalus Thank you for making me realize no assignment is considered an operator in Fortran. This makes so much sense why I couldn't do chain assignments, because they don't return anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to overload pointer assignment in Fortran 2018.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20080793/3157076) asks about using type-bound procedures to approach the overloading, but in the more general sense the answer is still no.

Up to Fortran 2018, the meaning of a pointer assignment statement

```
a => b
```

is always to affect the pointer status of the pointer `a` on the left-hand side.

Although the Fortran standard has *intrinsic* and *defined* assignment (this latter introduced with `interface assignment(=)`), there is no such distinction for pointer assignment.

Comment: So, you're saying this is available in the 2018 standard, or is still not available? That seems a little unclear to me. If so, read on please: @Steve's reply to my question mentioned how the compiler wouldn't quite know how to handle that, and it made me realize that this doesn't make sense without having an explicit dereference operator for pointers. If I had `type (my_type), pointer :: a` then say `a=>b`, is `a` modified as a pointer, or is the underlying object modified? (I'll admit I'm a C++ user by trade, so I apologize if my Fortran vocabulary seems off/wrong.)

Comment: Just a comment as you are coming from a C++ background: Pointers are a last resort in Fortran, you usually use other means to reach your ends. This is quite different from the C family of languages. So maybe if you say what you are really trying to do we can see a more Fortran way of doing it.

Comment: @madoflancashire, in Fortran, when a pointer appears somewhere it is usually the case that the pointer's _target_ is used (ie., the pointer is usually dereferenced).  With pointer assignment like `a=>b` the pointer `a`'s pointer association is changed.  A later reference like `a%x` will be to `b%x`.

Comment: Listen to Ian Bush's advice.  Fortran pointers are not the same thing as a C/C++ pointer.  Fortran pointers do have a place in the language, but if you can avoid them, then do.

Comment: @IanBush I need to be able to alias data, and possibly a lot of it, and possibly 3+ times at any given moment. Everything is held constant, so I don't have to worry about memory hazards. But, I wanted to save memory with multialiasing instead of outright copying. Therefore, I thought of pointers, since I can assign or allocate them at will. The function I call will take in not a matrix, but an array of arrays, since I wanted to alias each subarray separately.

Comment: Why do you NEED to alias data?

Comment: @IanBush To save memory. I'll have at least 3 different (more like 16) different arrays of data, and I'll be combining them in different ways. For the case of 3 arrays, there are 2^3-1=7 different ways of combining them. (For the case of 16 arrays, there are over 65000 combinations.) So, instead of copying them into a matrix, I wanted to have an array of array references (or pointers) that I can iterate over, and reference the original arrays. This saves me time in copying and saves memory use.